# Why isn't mutate working?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am seeing something I don't understand.

This one works, though it's super slow.

```
eo1$digest <- sapply(paste(eo1$EIN,eo1$NAME), digest)
```

This one doesn't work: all the digests are the same.

```
eo1 <- mutate(eo1, digest=digest(paste(EIN,NAME)))
```

This produces the values I'd expect!  EIN concatenated with NAME.

```
eo1 <- mutate(eo1, digest=paste(EIN,NAME))
```

But I need the hash of that.

Comment: Also see - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32465074/new-dataframe-column-as-function-digest-of-another-one-is-not-working-for-me

Comment: Wow you guys, that was awesome!  Thanks!